# SpelEvaluationException: Attempted to call method throwOnError(java.lang.Boolean) on null context object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, oauth2resourceserver

I'm having trouble associating an `accessDecisionManager` to the `httpSecurity` configuration of my resource server and using SpEL oauth2 expressions.

I think I've followed correctly what documentation and several related questions here in SO say on how to implement this, but I keep getting the same error.

Current resource server implementation is the following:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler oauthAccessDeniedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
        http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/authenticated/**")
            .access("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_USER','SCOPE_READ')")
            .expressionHandler(oauthExpressionHandler())
            .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager())
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(oauthAccessDeniedHandler)
            .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint(), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/authenticated/**"));               
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources
            .tokenServices(tokenServices);
        //.expressionHandler(oauthExpressionHandler);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler oauthExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationEntryPoint oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
        entryPoint.setRealmName("RealName");
        return entryPoint;
    }

    @Bean
    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters 
          = Arrays.asList(
            new ScopeVoter(),
            new RoleVoter(),
            new WebExpressionVoter(),
            new AuthenticatedVoter());
    
        return new UnanimousBased(decisionVoters);
    }
}
```

With this implementation I keep getting the following error:

```
14:52:52 TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.traceDebug: Writing [{timestamp=Fri Sep 16 14:52:52 WEST 2022, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, exception=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, trace=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression '#oauth2.throwOnError(hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_USER','SCOPE_READ'))'
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:33)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased.decide(UnanimousBased.java:68)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method throwOnError(java.lang.Boolean) on null context object
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.throwIfNotNullSafe(MethodReference.java:154)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueRef(MethodReference.java:83)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:70)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:91)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:117)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:308)
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:30)
    ... 67 more
, message=Failed to evaluate expression '#oauth2.throwOnError(hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_USER','SCOPE_READ'))', path=/authenticated/profile}]
```

If I remove `accessionDecisionManager` from `httpSecurity` everything seems to be working, don't understand why. I'd really like to use an `UnanimousBased` using those voters instead of using the default one (as far as I read the default is an `AffirmativeBased`). How can this be achieved / Does it make sense?

Don't know if it helps, I'm using spring-security-oauth2-2.3.6 and spring-security-core-5.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `WebExpressionVoter` uses `DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler` by default, which causes the failure when SpEL evaluates the expression `#oauth2`:

```
public class WebExpressionVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter<FilterInvocation> {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    private SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation> expressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();

    ...

    public void setExpressionHandler(SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation> expressionHandler) {
        this.expressionHandler = expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

Since this class provides a method to change the expressionHandler used, I just had to change it before adding the `WebExpressionVoter` instance to my `UnanimousBased`:

```
@Bean
protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
    WebExpressionVoter webExpressionVoter = new WebExpressionVoter();
    webExpressionVoter.setExpressionHandler(oauthExpressionHandler);
        
    List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters 
      = Arrays.asList(
        new ScopeVoter(),
        new RoleVoter(),
        webExpressionVoter,
        new AuthenticatedVoter());
        
    return new UnanimousBased(decisionVoters);
}
```